# We use nosql for mongodb in the same way we use sql for oracle?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, database, nosql

I will ask my question as an example . 
If we use ORACLE as a database , and if we want to get data from it what we should know is SQL . with the help of an sql we can get the data from oracle.

If we use Mongo db as a database do we have to know about NoSql . ??

in simpler terms .
SQL for ORACLE . And NoSql for MongoDB ? am i right .?

Comment: NoSQL is a generic term for everything other than...SQL.

Comment: SQL it is language, and with this language you could write queries to Oracle, MySQL, MS SQL and another Relational Database Management Systems. NoSQL = "Not Only SQL", but it is not a lanquage, it is a generic name for No Relational Databases. And if you asking about language for write queries to MongoDB, it is JavaScript with some specific syntax for MongoDB.

Comment: yeah i get that . So my assumptions are right isn't it joao .?

Comment: Okay .. if we want to fetch data from MongoDB , how can we do that ? Ivan.Srb

Comment: You could read this tutorial http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as *the* NoSQL query language. All the databases usually grouped under the catch-all label "NoSQL" are completely different technologies which are used in completely different ways.

MongoDB has a query language which is based on javascript object notations. It doesn't have much to do with SQL and not anything either with the query languages of most other NoSQL databases. [An interactive tutorial can be found on the MongoDB website](http://try.mongodb.org/). It should give you a basic understanding of how the query language works. [The full documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) is a good source of in-depth knowledge.

Keep in mind that when you learned everything about MongoDB and its query language, you still know absolutely nothing about other NoSQL databases like Redis, Neo4j, CouchDB etc.. These are as different from MongoDB (and as different from each other) as MongoDB is different from SQL databases.

Comment: when i first read your reply i cant understand it. But now after doing some simple queries i got it cleared . thanks.